# Number of variables in the Hamilton-Jacobi equation

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, time, hamiltonian-formalism, differential-equations

In Goldstein's *Classical Mechanics*, while introducing the Hamilton-Jacobi equation, he argues that the equation $$H(q_1, ... , q_n; \frac{\partial S}{\partial q_1}, ..., \frac{\partial S}{\partial q_n}; t) + \frac{\partial S}{\partial t} = 0$$ is a partial differential equation in $(n + 1)$ variables $q_1, ... , q_n; t$.

He then proceeds to say that the solution (if it exists) will be of the form $$S(q_1, ... , q_n; \alpha_1, ... , \alpha_{n+1}; t)$$ where the quantities $\alpha_1, ... , \alpha_{n+1}$ are the $(n + 1)$ constants of integration.

How is time a variable? Isn't it the parameter we're integrating over?

Perhaps this warrants some context. He introduces the Hamilton-Jacobi equation with the motivation to find a canonical transformation that relates the canonical coordinates at a time $t$ -- $(q(t), p(t))$ -- and the initial coordinates $(q_o, p_o)$ at $t = 0$. I hence get that time must be a variable here. However, it is still the parameter we integrate the Hamilton-Jacobi over in order to get $S$, right? Where does the $(n+1)^{th}$ constant of integration come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The [HJ equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation) is a non-linear 1st-order [PDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation) in $n+1$ variables $(q^1,\ldots,q^n,t)$, namely the generalized positions and time, which in principle enter on equal footing.
2. A complete$^1$ solution, known as Hamilton's principal function $S(q,\alpha,t)$, should not be conflated with the off-shell action functional $S[q;t_f,t_i]$ nor the (Dirichlet) on-shell action $S(q_f,t_f;q_i,t_i)$, cf. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/90857/2451).

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics;* Section 10.1 first footnote.
2. L.D. Landau & E.M. Lifshitz, *Mechanics,* vol. 1 (1976); $\S$47 footnote on p. 148.

--

$^1$ A [complete solution to a 1st-order PDE is *not* a general solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_partial_differential_equation#General_solution_and_complete_integral) [1,2], despite the name!

Answer (score 1):

the action function in the HJ formalism is dependent on time through the upper bound.

$$S(q_i,t,\alpha_i,t_0)=\int_{t_0}^tL(q_i,\partial_tq_i,t')dt'$$
in cases of Lagrangian that is independent (explicitly) of time then the constant of integration conjugate to $t$ let's call it $\alpha_t$ is simply the Energy.

read more here:
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation#Hamilton's_principal_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation#Hamilton%27s_principal_function)