# What is the physical significance of a Lagrangian and an action in particle physics?

Tags: particle-physics, lagrangian-formalism, action

I’m currently studying for a particle physics module about the standard model and there is a lot of material on Lagrangians (curly L) and actions (S).

I’m not quite sure what both of these quantities signify/mean physically. From what I gather a Lagrangian kind of describes the energies that contribute to particular forms of matter but I may be wrong.

If anyone can give me a reasonably simple description of what these quantities do/describe I would appreciate it.

Comment: Read first here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41138/

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9686/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41138/2451 and links therein.